# How do I know how many times the github actions I published have been used?

Tags: github, github-actions

As the title.
I publish a GitHub Action, I want know the usage statistics.
GitHub doesn't seem to have this feature？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem so I created a platform to do just that.
Head over to [actions.boringday.co](https://actions.boringday.co/get-started) to get started.
Here is a screenshot of what I get with my action: `version-bumper`
[image]